# Node.js: strange symbol "^@" using fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, vim, mips, writefile

I've built and run Node.js on emmbed linux-os with MIPS 24K Little Endian CPU. Node.js version is v0.12.0. Everything works fine except when I use fs.writeFile, example code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.txt","hello world!",'utf-8', function(err){
        if(err){
                return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("saved");
});
```

Using vim to check this test.txt, the content is:

```
^@hello world!
```

Obviously, there's an undesireable symbol "^@" in the beginning of the written file.

So how does this problem happen and how to solve it?

Comment: ^@ means that there are much more lines, preferably long lines behind by current line, I think. There is nothing to worry about ^@, I have seen it several times in a large script or log file. Its a visual representation in vim I think.

Comment: Try printing the content of a file through commands like cat. It won't show such characters

Comment: @SibiCoder command 'cat' not show such characters.However the real content of the written file is in json format, this file will be used by others. I think I cannot just ignore it

Comment: As far as I know, they are just representational characters in vim, not the original content of any file.

Comment: @SibiCoder When I use fs.appendFile instead of fs.writeFile, in vim these characters are gone, this confuse me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

*First* thing to do is to try retyping the `hello world` string, it may be that you've somehow inserted a `NUL`, or <kbd>CTRL-@</kbd> character into it before the `h`. ECMAScript actually allows this, as `NUL` is *not* one of the characters forbidden to appear in a string literal.

You could check this before-hand by doing a hex dump of the source file to see what actual characters are in there.

Comment: Thx for the reply. It's very strange because using the same source file on PC, the output file is fine. While using fs.appendFile on this mips board, it also works fine, so I have no idea why fs.writeFile fails.